# Choice of article in "The larger the (a) company is, the more complex its management system is"

Tags: articles

1. The larger **a** company is, the more complex its management system is.
2. The larger **the** company is, the more complex its management system is.

Are the two options fully analogous?

I'm writing a very short text describing a typical company's structure.

I seem to find examples of both **a** and **the** used in this construction on the web.

> The larger the company is, the more responsibility the CEO has.
>   The larger a company is, the greater in general will be its willingness to assume social responsibility.

(these examples are from Google Books)

My draft is:

> On a general scale, a typical company consists of the shareholders, the management and the workforce. The larger **(a/the)** company is, the more complex its management system is.

Comment: Is the overall topic of your draft "companies" or "management systems"?

Comment: @user3169 - "The structure of a typical company".

Comment: **a**: instance of the general rule;   **the**:  instance of the general rule perceived as an exemplar or as a particular case.  For all intents and purposes interchangeable.

Comment: I'd say you could also write companies (without articles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context you describe, I would probably use *the*.  What determines which article to use is whether you are referring to a previously mentioned company, or introducing the company for the first time.  So if, in your second sentence, you mean to refer to the "typical company" you mention in your first sentence, you would use *the*.  If you intend to make a statement about companies in general, you would use *a*.  (As a further example of the idea, I might just as well have said *if you intend the second sentence to be about companies in general*...)

This should also explain why you find examples of both.  While they are not fully analogous, to some extent they overlap in usage.